# Is there surjective homomorphism of the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 - 6_1^2)$ onto the dihedral group $D_{2\cdot 3}$ of $6$ elements?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-homomorphism, knot-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I am studying for my topology qualifying exam. I am stuck on showing if there is a surjective homomorphism from the fundamental group of the knot complement of $6_1^2$ shown below to the dihedral group of order $6$.

[image]

Assuming that I have calculated the fundamental group correctly, I have the presentation

$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 - 6_1^2) = \langle a,b \mid ababab = bababa \rangle$$

and, of course,

$$D_6 = \langle r,s \mid r^3 = s^2 =1, rs = sr^{-1}\rangle $$ I'm really stuck on finding a homomorphism that makes sense (assuming that a surjective one does in fact exist). So let $\phi:\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 - 6_1^2) \to D_6$ be our homomorphism. I've tried $\phi(a) = r$ (which means that $\phi(a)^2 = r^2 = r^{-1})$  and $\phi(babab) = s$. I know that I need $\phi(ababab) = \phi(bababa)$ in order for this to be a homomorphism.
But the mapping above gives

$$rsr = \phi(a)\phi(babab)\phi(a) = \phi(abababa) = \phi(bababaa) = \phi(babab)\phi(a^2) = \phi(babab)\phi(a)^2 = sr^2 = sr^{-1}$$

Thus,

$$rsr = sr^{-1} \implies rsr^2 = s \implies rsr^{-1} = s \implies rs = sr$$

which isn't true.

Another mapping I've had suggested to me is $\phi(a) = r$ and $\phi(bababa^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1})$ = s but then

$rs = \phi(a)\phi(bababa^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1})) = \phi (abababa^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}) = \phi(1) = \phi(bababab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}) = \phi(bababab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1})\phi(a^{-1}) = sr^{-1}$

Now $rs = sr^{-1}$ but since a homorphism must map the identity $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 - 6_1^2)$ to the identity of $D_6$, this would imply that $rs = id_{D_6}$, which is a contradiction.

*Please note that I have minimal knot theory knowledge and am looking for an explanation using algebra. Thank you for your consideration.*

Update: I think I may have found a homomorphism: $\phi(a)=s$, $\phi(b)=rs$, so $$\phi(ababab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)=s(rs)s(rs)s(rs)=r^{−3}=id$$ and $$\phi(bababa)=\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)=(rs)s(rs)s(rs)s=r^3=id$$ so $\phi(ababab)=\phi(bababa)$ and it's nontrivial. And it's surjective since we can generate D6 with s and rs. Does this look right?

Comment: Given the shape of the knot, one would assume that the natural action of $D_6$ on the space would be relevant.

Comment: Just saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388030/surjection-pi-1-s3-4-1-to-d-n?rq=1), where it doesn't work.

Comment: Based on that, @DietrichBurde, there should be a nontrivial homomorphism.

Comment: I think I may have found a homomorphism: $\phi(a) = s$, $\phi(b) = rs$, so $\phi(ababab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b) = s(rs)s(rs)s(rs) = r^{-3} = id$ and $\phi(bababa) = \phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a) = (rs)s(rs)s(rs)s = r^3 = id$, so $\phi(ababab) = \phi(bababa)$ and it's nontrivial. And it's subjective since we can generated $D_6$ with $s$ and $rs$. Does this look right?

Comment: A couple hints: To be surjective, you need every meridian (a loop that goes to the knot, makes a small loop around, then comes back to the base point) to map to an element of the form $r^ks$, otherwise you can show the image will be the subgroup generated by $r$ (one way: consider the abelianization). Thus, a homomorphism is equivalently a way to label each arc in the diagram by $0$, $1$, or $2$ for what that meridian maps to. Next, you can work out around each crossing a linear equation mod 3 that these assignments have to satisfy. The Wirtinger presentation is helpful here.

Comment: So, this has a surjective homomorphism given by what I commented above? I found a labeling of the arcs that respects the linear equation at each crossing.

Comment: I didn't carefully check your work, but using $s$ and $rs$ seems right, and I know that this knot has a surjective homomorphism to $D_6$. (It's "Fox 3-colorable.")