# Determining whether two groups are isomorphic based on Wirtinger presentation

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, knot-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am working on knot theory and basic algebraic topology. In order to prove that the figure eight knot and the trefoil knot are not isotopic, I have to show that their knot groups (i.e. the fundamental groups of their complements) are not isomorphic, using their Wirtinger presentation.

The groups are the following: $$G(H) = \langle a, d \mid a d a^{-1} d a = d a d^{-1} a d \rangle$$ and $$G(T_1) = \langle p, q \mid q^2 = p^3 \rangle.$$
Of course, these groups are without torsion, so I cannot use any argument about orders of elements.

How can I proceed? Thank very much.

Comment: For an easy proof using colourings see Corollary $1.2$ [here](https://pillowmath.github.io/Math%20142/Lec24.pdf).

Comment: You can use the fact that there is a epimorphism from the trefoil group to the cyclic group of order 3 (or the dihedral group of order 6) and there is not one from the figure-8 knot group -- if you want a purely group theoretic proof.

Comment: @N.Owad And to add a proof (from yourself) to the fact that the figure eight knot has none to $D_3$ (but trefoil has), see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388030/surjection-pi-1-s3-4-1-to-d-n) - again by $3$-coloring.

Comment: @N.Owad They both have epimorphisms to the cyclic group of order $3$, but not to the dihedral group of order $6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oops!  Thank you for catching that!

Comment: @DietrichBurde When I read this I wondered if this was done out already here.  It is funny when one forgets that they have already done just that...  And I took your first answer to be a proof by just "coloring" as opposed to the group theory version of coloring, having not followed the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is N. Owad's remark, just spelled out]

The second group affords an epimorphism to $S_3$, namely $p\mapsto (1,2,3)$, $q\mapsto(1,2)$. On the other hand, the first group affords no such epimorphism (try out all 36 possible generator images, use van Dyck's theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I did not know about Van Dyck's theorem and just got the opportunity to read about it, very interesting.